# Тест: некорректный подсчет правильных ответов

Tags: php

Очень нужна ваша помощь. Через 4 часа сдавать. Имею тест. Вопросы достаю из БД.

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'ItEconom', '22304qqq');
mysql_select_db('IT', $db);

$myrow  = mysql_query("SELECT question, var1, var2, var3, var4,var5,var6,var7 FROM     testProc3 ");
$count  = 0;
$arr[0] = 0;
While ($count < 20) {
    $a = false;
    while (!$a) {
        $count2 = 0;
        $num    = rand(1, mysql_num_rows($myrow) - 1);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            if ($num != $arr[$i])
                $count2++;            
        }
        if ($count2 == count($arr)) {
            $arr[$count] = $num;
            $a           = true;
        }
    }
    $count++;
    echo "<form action = 'handler.php' method = 'Post' name = 'Post'>";
    printf("%s<br><label><input type = 'radio' name = 'id[%s][1]' value = '1'></label> а) %s<br><input type = 'radio' name = 'id[%s][2]' value = '2'></label> б) %s<br><input type = 'radio' name = 'id[%s][3]' value = '3'></label> в) %s<br>", mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'question'), $num, mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var1'), $num, mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var2'), $num, mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var3'));

    if (mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var4') != null) {
        echo "<input type = 'radio' name = id[" . $num . "][4] value = '4'></label> г) " . mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var4') . '<br>';
    }
    if (mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var5') != null) {
        echo "<input type = 'radio' name = id[" . $num . "][5] value = '5'></label> д) " . mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var5') . '<br>';
    }
    if (mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var6') != null) {
        echo "<input type = 'radio' name = id[" . $num . "][6] value = '6'></label> е) " . mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var6') . '<br>';
    }
    if (mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var7') != null) {
        echo "<input type = 'radio' name = id[" . $num . "][7] value = '7'></label> ж) " . mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var7') . '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';

}
echo ' <input type="submit"  value = "Показать результаты"/>';
echo "</form>";

?>
```

Вот обработчик:

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'ItEconom', '22304qqq');
mysql_select_db('IT', $db);
$pravOtv = 0;
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i) {
    //echo $i;
    foreach ($i as $j) {
        $otv  = 0;
        $svet = 0;
        for ($count = 1; $count < 8; $count++) {
            $tmp = mysql_query("select * FROM testProc3");
            echo mysql_result($tmp, $i, 'otv' . $count);

            if (intval(mysql_result($tmp, $i, 'otv' . $count)))
                ++$svet; // Проверяю сколько всего правильных вариантов ответа в БД

            if ($j == mysql_result($tmp, $i, 'otv' . $count)) // Проверяю совпадают ли мои ответы с правильными
                {
                $otv++;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($svet == $otv)
        $pravOtv++; // Если кол-во вариантов ответа совпало с решенными, то имеем один правильный ответ.

}

echo '  <div class = "print" >Правильных ответов: ' . $pravOtv . '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: В итоге постоянно получаю: правильных ответов:0
P.S. Не важно что код некорректный. В данный момент, главное, чтобы он заработал и меня допустили к экзамену )

Comment: А экзамен будешь своему скрипту сдавать?

Answer (score 4):

Код, увы, невозможно читать и разбирать, какая-то мешанина. Плюс, оно концептуально неверно — если оно как-то и будет работать, то это будет случайность, а не нормальное поведение. И далеко *не факт*, что эта случайность повторится при сдаче.

Без обид, но это намного проще выкинуть и переписать по-уму, чем исправить. По крайней мере, в танцах в цикле, где составлялась какая-то структура данных с вопросами, я потерялся. На ночь глядя разобрать что там творится (осмысленные имена переменных `$a` не способствуют) сложно.

В таблице первичным ключом нужен столбец `id`, уникально идентифицирующий вопрос. Потому что две выборки `SELECT * FROM table` *могут* вернуть ряды в разном порядке. А Вы привязываетесь к этому порядку.

Можно без id, но тогда описывайте структуру таблицы, в частности, что является первичным ключом. Возможно, придется использовать, например, SHA1 от текста вопроса (считая что коллизии не наступит). Но лучше все-таки добавить суррогатный первичный ключ (`id`), если его нет — дел на секунду, а ситуацию упрощает.

Выдача вопросов:

```
<?php
    // Функции `mysql_*` давно deprecated. Ими не стоит пользоваться.
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=IT", "ItEconom", "22304qq");

    // Выбираем 20 вопросов, сортируя по случайным числам, чем обеспечиваем
    // перемешивание. $sth — результат запроса, дальше вытаскиваем массив
    // массивов в $questions.
    $sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM testProc3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
    $questions = $sth->fetchAll();

    $letters = array("а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "е", "ж");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Тест</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="handler.php" method="post">
<?php
    // Выводим список вопросов. Не очень красиво, но обойдемся без шаблонизатора.
    foreach ($questions as $question) {
?>
        <section>
            <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($question["question"]); ?></p>
            <p>
<?php
            // Пробегаемся по столбцам `var$i`
            for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                // Если очередное поле ­NULL — закругляемся с этим вопросом
                if (is_null($question["var$i"])) break;
?>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $question["id"] ?>]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <?php echo $letters[$i], ") ",
                               htmlspecialchars($question["var$i"]); ?>
                </label>
<?php
            }
?>
            </p>
        </section>
<?php
    }
?>
        <input type="sumbit" value="Получить результаты">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Проверка ответов:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=IT", "ItEconom", "22304qq");

    // Подготавливаем запрос. Каждый раз как будем делать $check->execute(...)
    // будет выполняться такой запрос, с подставленным значением вместо «?»
    $check = $db->prepare("SELECT otv FROM testProc3 WHERE id = ?");

    $correct = 0;
    // Пробегаемся по ответам
    foreach($_POST["answer"] as $id => $answer) {
        // Выбираем правильный ответ для вопроса с ID = $id
        // NB: `execute` хочет в аргументы массив, пусть даже из одного элемента.
        $check->execute(array($id));
        if ($answer == $check->fetchColumn()) {
            // Правильный ответ — увеличиваем счетчик
            $correct += 1;
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Результат</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Правильных ответов: <b><?php echo $correct; ?></b>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Одно «но» — я не понял про «число правильных ответов» (на вопрос). Исходя из того, что у Вас `<input type="radio" ...>`, предположу, что правильный ответ один. Если много — это уже был бы `type="checkbox"` и усложнение логики:

Тогда в форме было бы:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer[<?php echo $question["id"] ?>][]" value="<?php echo $i ?>">
```

И при проверке `$answer` у нас был бы массивом. Предположим, в поле `otv` хранятся ответы в виде строки, с числами через запятую. Тогда код проверки был бы в духе:

```
$check->execute(array($id));
$correct_answer = explode(",", $check->fetchColumn()); // Массив правильных ответов
// Вычисляем различия между массивами
$diff = array_diff($answer, $correct_answer);
if (count($diff) == 0) {
    // Пустой массив различий значит что их не было (порядок не важен,
    // тут массивами оперировали как множествами)
    $correct += 1;
}
```

(Но недопустимо иметь вопросы, где нет ни одного правильного ответа — тогда никакого `answer[N][]` не передастся и мы вообще проигнорируем существование вопроса. Надеюсь, это допустимо — такой расклад экономит нам время, упрощая обработку формы.

Код не проверял, писал в браузере. С поправкой на опечатки должно работать.

*Обновление:* Исправил ошибки, забыл в первом скрипте сделать `fetchAll()` и забыл `value` у `<input>`'ов. Теперь вроде как должно — проверить, увы, негде — ни веб-сервера с PHP ни MySQL/MariaDB-сервера нет в доступном окружении, а ставить мне лень, уж извините.